# Error in source: Unexpected symbol

Tags: r

I keep receiving this error but cannot work out what is wrong in my source.

```
Error in source("/Users/oscarbaker/Documents/Dissertation/R/Moisture_Monthly.Rd") : 
  /Users/oscarbaker/Documents/Dissertation/R/Moisture_Monthly.Rd:41:1: unexpected symbol
40: 
41: matplot
   ^
```

This is most of my source:

```
Moisture_Names = c("DIM","MONTH","YEAR","Hour","Mins","DOY","TMN_2","TMN_5","TMN_10","TMN_30","TMN_50","TMN_65","TMS_2","TMS_5","TMS_10","TMS_20","TMS_40","TMS_60","TMW_2","TMW_5","TMW_10","TMW_20","TMW_40","TMW_60","TMW_80","TMW_100","TPN_8","TPN_20","TPN_40","TPN_65","CS616S_L8","CS616S_L20","CS616S_L40","CS616S_L68","CS616S_Q8","CS616S_Q20","CS616S_Q40","CS616S_Q68")

file2012 <- read.csv("/Users/oscarbaker/Documents/Dissertation/Datasets/Soil_Moisture_12.csv", header=T", sep=",", col.names=Moisture_Names)
file2013 <- read.csv("/Users/oscarbaker/Documents/Dissertation/Datasets/Soil_Moisture_13.csv", header="T", sep=",", col.names=Moisture_Names)

#Jan

matplot(Jan2012$DOY,Jan2012$TMN_2, type="l", lty="1", col="1", xlim=c(0,32), ylim=c(0,70), xlab="Day Number", ylab="Moisture Content")
points(Jan2012$DOY,Jan2012$TMN_5, type="l", lty="2", col="1")
```

There must be a mistake in there somewhere but i cannot see it

Comment: This is hard to answer without seeing lines 40 and 41 of your source file.

Comment: This is likely caused by a syntax error in your file (missing a closing: parenthesis, curly-brace, bracket, quote, etc.).

Comment: line 41 is the matplot line under #Jan

Comment: and line 40 is the blank line in between #Jan and matplot

Comment: ok well your last line of code before 41 then...

Comment: ive updated it, sorry never used one of these sites before

Comment: @user3249039 your first header=T" occurrence is missing the opening quote like on the second line which have header="T"... refering to file2012 and file2013

Comment: ah thanks, however that has not solved the problem..

Comment: Change both occurrences of `header=...` to `header=TRUE`

Comment: tried that but still the same issue

Answer (score 4):

The brilliant code formatting of SO for code shows you your error straight away.

Its this line:

```
file2012 <- read.csv("/Users/oscarbaker/Documents/Dissertation/Datasets/Soil_Moisture_12.csv", header=T", sep=",", col.names=Moisture_Names)
```

(edited by cgw)
You miss a quote, it should be header = TRUE.  Do not put quotes around the `logical` values `TRUE` or `FALSE` .  It's also important to get used to using "TRUE" rather than "T" -- just ask the geneticists :-)

Comment: this hasn't resolved the issue unfortunately

Comment: I'm assuming you spotted that both the 2012 and 2013 lines were missing there closing quotes?

Comment: which closing quotes? i cant see any missing

Comment: its basic debugging dude. Run your code line by line until you get an error. These error messages aren't always the solution.